# How to position a fixed box in relation to the main content area not the window?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have a box filled with contact information at the top of my webpage and I coded it with fixed positioning. The box follows you up and down the screen. I noticed after that was done that if i change the width of the window that it moves the contact box left to right.

I cant seem to figure out how to have the contact box move up and down the screen without moving left to right with different monitors and resolutions. I dont know if fixed positioning is the right answer because that is in relation to the screen?

```
CSS(minimum case):
    position: fixed;
    right: 24.2%;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
```

Comment: Im trying to have the box stay on the right side of the main content area and scroll up and down no matter where the screen is. For example: the facebook menu bar that follows you down the screen, but i want it to be a 250px wide box, not the full length of the screen.

Comment: I believe i just answered my own question with the facebook example. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved this problem was by wrapping a div(lets call it wrapper) around whatever element i wanted to have fixed. I then gave the wrapper a fixed positioning with `top:0` and now left or right param and i also gave it a width of the content area which was 980px. After that all i had to do was float the inside element to the right and it stayed there. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed left position instead of a percentage right one which [without providing a layout] is most likely based on window width.

```
left: 200px;
```

Comment: I tried that and it makes the box move in relation to the side of the screen or its starting point by 200px. If i minimize the screen the box stays that 200px distance from the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try `position:relative;` in the parent element and see if it works